# issue with uninstalling infragistics

Tags: infragistics, uninstallation

My department is upgrading to a newer version of infragistics and I was told that I need to uninstall the older version and install the new version.

I went into Control panel and simply go through the list and one by one try to uninstall each of the Infragistics packages or whatever you call it.

Some of them uninstall just fine, some of them give me an error saying:

> There is a problem with this Windows Installer Package. A program run
>   as part of the setup did not finish as expected. contact your support
>   personnel or package vendor.

This specific error comes up when I try to uninstall:

```
Infragistics NetAdvantage Windows Forms 2012.2 Help
```

This seems to happen for pretty much most of the packages, so another one's I'm getting the same error with are:

```
Infragistics NetAdvantage Reporting 2012.2 Help
Infragistics NetAdvantage ASP.NET 2012.2 Help
```

Comment: 1) Restart the Windows. 2) Try to uninstall one more time. 3) If error is happened examine the Windows Logs in the Event Viewer for more detailed error description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you have found out an Infragistics' forum thread, where I was working on a similar issue, describing exactly the approach I described there for resolving it.

The whole process of installing and possibly corrupting the installation would be like the following copied exactly from the forum thread:

[https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/f/ultimate-ui-for-windows-forms/89266/uninstallation-of-infragistics-windows-forms-2013-3-help](https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/f/ultimate-ui-for-windows-forms/89266/uninstallation-of-infragistics-windows-forms-2013-3-help/)

> 1. Install VS 2010 and VS 2012 on a Windows 7 machine.
> 2. Install Infragistics Windows Forms 2013 vol2 and Infragistics Windows Forms 2014 vol1 on that machine.
> 3. Uninstall VS 2012 from the machine.
> 4. Uninstall Infragistics 2013 vol2 Help.
>
> Since the above operations completed successfully, we have reinstalled
>   some of the packages back and started to corrupt them in order to try
>   to get similar behavior as in your case.  At the end we got similar
>   behavior as you have mentioned after the following steps were taken:
>
> 1. Visual Studio 2012 Uninstalled, and HelpViewer 2.0 installed (Basically this help viewer 2.0 comes and goes with the Visual Studio
>      2012)
> 2. Then when you start the installer "it believes" that you still have Visual Studio 2012 installed on your machine(which isn't true
>      anymore).
> 3. When it reaches the point to actually uninstall the content from Visual Studio 2012 it looks for the following catalog name
>      VisualStudio11 in here -
>      C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\HelpLibrary2\Catalogs , which in that case
>      might be not there anymore.
>
> The easiest approach to uninstall the Infragistics Windows Forms Help
>   2013 vol2 would be to go to your registry entries (if your machine is
>   x64 bits) and temporary Rename the following one -
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Help\v2.0 to
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Help\v2.9. If the
>   machine is 32 bits, the registry entry would be like -
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Help\v2.0. So the next time when
>   you run your .msi installer, it won't find that Help Viewer 2.0 (which
>   actually should work only with Visual Studio 2012 installed), and the
>   Uninstallation process may complete successfully.
>
> If for some reason the uninstallation fails again, you would have to
>   first "Repair" the Help 2013 vol2 .msi, and then "Uninstall" it, while
>   still keeping the registry entry changed. Once you are done with that
>   process and you the help is uninstalled successfully you could rename
>   back the registry entry to its initial value.

Actually Infragistics' versions could live side by side, and it is not needed to uninstall the previous version, when you would like to upgrade to a newer one.

I am glad that I was able to help you indirectly here, but you proved to have a great researching skills :)

Sincerely,

Comment: Yes I believe I came across a similar article. Thanks for your input. I did not uninstall VS2012 or the TFS. I simply changed the Registry Folders and Repaird/Uninstalled the Help files.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...
With older versions of Infragistics, you end up with 3 different files for each package:

```
Infragistics NetAdvantage Windows Forms 2012.2
Infragistics NetAdvantage Windows Forms 2012.2 Samples
Infragistics NetAdvantage Windows Forms 2012.2 Help
```

I had no issue uninstalling the top two, I only had issues with the 'Help' files.

After some research I was able to uninstall all those 'Help' files and install the newer version of Infragistics and get it to work successfully.

Here's what I did:

-Go to Registry Editor
-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE --> SOFTWARE --> MICROSOFT --> HELP

-under HELP you will have either 1 or 2 folders called v1.0 or/and v2.0.

Change v2.0 to v2.9 - if you both then change v2.0 only or if you only have v1.0, then change that to v1.9. Go back to Control Panel --> Programs and Features --> Repair the problematic Infragistic 'Help' files and you should be able to uninstall them. Once you are done with all the files, simply rename your v2.9 or v1.9 folder back to what it was before.